# BxSlider - reassign the slider to different element

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am using this [BxSlider  plugin](http://bxslider.com/)  which i need to reassign to a different element according to what `<ul>` element is visible. How can I remove the slider from the element set on page load to a different element ?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.welcome_sections .menu').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 1,
      maxSlides: 7,
      slideWidth: 120,
      slideMargin: 10
    }); 

});
```

I want reload the slider on a different element. 
I tried the following but doesn't work

```
slider = $('.welcome_sections .menu2').bxSlider();
slider.reloadSlider();
```

Answer (score 1):

reloadSlider() only works when you are modifying the content and need to reinitialize on the same element. But I've found I needed to first .destroySlider() and then create it again on a new element.

```
var slider = $('.welcome_sections .menu').bxSlider(default_args);
...
slider.destroySlider();
slider = $('.welcome_sections .menu2').bxSlider(default_args);
```